# Unit testing advice on an object with many properties

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm fairly new to unit testing but I completely get the idea of testing individual units of code that perform a specific, testable task, however, I'm in a position where I need to write tests and provide confidence in the accuracy of an output of a method that acts on an object with over 50 properties. The combinations of the values of these properties produce an output based on rules injected from a rule definition object (using lambda expressions) which essentially equates to a percentage. These output percentages are "mission critical" and have been rather lazily tested previously, for example the quality of the rule definition class (do all the attributable percentages for each rule add up to 100%) but the actual properties of the object haven't been.

The "data" object comes from a database but I can, of course, mock it. My problem is the number of permutations of data that would need mocking and the amount of tests that would need to be written to ensure that data x,y,z (times 50 odd exponential) feels near impossible.

So, the question is, how are these situations testable in a real sense. Is scripting tests based on a known "correct" state and "correct" results even possible/sensible? Are unit tests applicable in this case and if not what alternatives are there.

By the way, this is legacy code here with a small opportunity to refactor but only if I can guarantee accuracy etc within timescales of a couple of days to do both the refactor and the tests!

Comment: Lol - can you believe written on my iPhone? Damn you predictive text. Will sort the grammar out when I have a real keyboard in front if me :)

Comment: @S.Lott We could also try not to be anal about typos, couldn't we? There, I've corrected it. ;)

Comment: And now @S.Lott, your comment has been flagged. No need for such behaviour, especially considering the fact that it was typed out on a mobile device.

Comment: Here's my point.  Not that it matters any more.  We read and respond to the question -- as written.  Then.  Some time later, the question is rewritten.   What now?  We've responded inappropriately to a question which later got revised.  The poor person framing the question now has answers that are useless.  What's the person supposed to do now?  How do they get people to re-read it after the edits?  I thought that a little preliminary editing would be helpful.  I guess the majority feel that my suggestion is  worthy of moderator deletion.

Comment: @S.Lott It's strange that you've commented on a question related to agile development and have so little agile thinking...  If the question can be edited, so can the answers.  If the question is revised, to make it more precise and/or understandable, the answers can, too.  If you feel you were treated unfairly, and really want to find out how the majority feel about this, read the answer to this meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: @weltraumpirat: I'm aware that updates are possible.  I was trying to make the point that a question entered in haste -- with errors -- for which later editing was the intent, sounds like a way to get hasty answers that aren't useful.  Clearly, you disagree and feel that a question which requires correction is better than a question which is already in a largely finished form.  I apologize for bringing up that idea that a question should be largely finalized before being presented to the world.

Comment: Clearly there is no point in continuing this discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've given half of your answer yourself:

> The combinations of the values of these properties produce an output
>   based on rules **injected** from a rule definition object (using lambda
>   expressions) which essentially equates to a percentage.

In your current unit test, you'd be **mocking both the data and the rule**. Therefore, you'd need only to ensure that the in- and output methods behave correctly.

Testing the rule is a different task.  I can only guess, but usually, you'll have an Excel table, or something like that, of possible in- and output values to specify the requirements for this rule.  I would convert that same table to a readable (csv) format, and use it directly to drive the rule's unit test.

Answer (score 4):

If it is the sheer amount of combinations that is holding you back in trying to generate testcases, you could take a look at **[all-pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) testing**.

We have used [PICT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/testing/bb980925.aspx) from microsoft to successfully minimize the amount of testcases while still having reasonable confidence to have most cases covered.

> **Summary**
>
> For instance, if you wish to create a test suite for partition and
>   volume creation, the domain can be described by the following
>   parameters: Type, Size, File system, Format method, Cluster size, and
>   Compression. Each parameter has a limited number of possible values,
>   each of which is determined by its nature (for example, Compression
>   can only be On or Off) or as an equivalence partition (such as Size).
>
> Type:          Primary, Logical, Single, Span, Stripe, Mirror, RAID-5
>   Size:          10, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000, 40000
>   Format method: quick, slow
>   File system:   FAT, FAT32, NTFS
>   Cluster size:  512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536
>   Compression:   on, off
>
> There are over 4,700 possible combinations of these values. It would
>   be very difficult to test all of them in a reasonable amount of time.
>   Research shows that testing all pairs of possible values provides very
>   good coverage and the number of test cases will remain manageable. For
>   example, {Primary, FAT} is one pair and {10, slow} is another; a
>   single test case can cover many pairs.
>
> For the set of parameters shown above, PICT will produce 60 test
>   cases.

**Takeaway points**

- there are over 4,700 possible combinations
- PICT will produce 60 testcases

> **All Pairs**
>
> The reasoning behind all-pairs testing
>   is this: the simplest bugs in a
>   program are generally triggered by a
>   single input parameter.
>
> The next simplest category of bugs consists of
>   those dependent on interactions
>   between pairs of parameters, which can
>   be caught with all-pairs testing.
>
> Bugs involving interactions between
>   three or more parameters are
>   progressively less common, whilst
>   at the same time being progressively
>   more expensive to find by exhaustive
>   testing, which has as its limit the
>   exhaustive testing of all possible
>   inputs.

Comment: Not sure that this is exactly, what the question was asking, but a **very** concise and helpful answer none the less.  An excellent explanation of all pairs testing and what the benefit of it is.

Comment: @mklauber - OP states that *'My problem is the number of permutations '* so I assumed All Pairs testing would be relevant to OP.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know in what language you are working, but after looking in your profile I think .Net might be involved.

If I am right with this, I would suggest using Data Driven Tests. MSDN provides a short Quick Start, which helped me very much to dice in: [How to: Create a Data-Driven Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx)
Since I read this article I startetd to invent a new variation to use in every new project...

Working with these DDT in Visual Studio enables you to store your test datain XML, CSV, or in a database table. Perhaps it is possible for you to write some code to generate the neccesary values to insert into the tests?

A second advice would the [Pex and Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/downloads.aspx) project by Microsoft that analyses your system under test and on this basis automatically generates test data to find more extreme test cases.